# Why does math.infinity turn to a big negative integer when overwriting in some cases?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to overwrite some array values for a min-finding algorithm.
For these examples, I want the values of the first row to be replaced by `math.inf`.

It works fine in example `c`, but I don't understand what happens in `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np
import math

a = np.repeat(0, 9).reshape((3, 3))
a[0, :] = np.ones((3,)) * math.inf
print(a)

b = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
b[0, :] = np.ones((3,)) * math.inf
print(b)

c = np.empty((3, 3))
c[0, :] = np.ones((3,)) * math.inf
print(c)
```

Output: shows infinity as the row entry in example `c`, but `-9223372036854775808` in example `a` and `b`.

[image]

Why does the existing output have an influence when I overwrite it?

Comment: It has to do with the *dtype* of your arrays: `a` and `b` are *int64* while `c` is *float64*. Do note that `math.inf` is also a *float*. So assigning it to an *int* would somewhat suggest it will get cast. The weird part is `a[0, :] = math.inf` will cast the row to `-9223372036854775808` (the biggest representable *long*, although I'm not sure about the minus sign). ***Yet*** `a[0, np.arange(a.shape[1])] = math.inf` (which should perfom the same operation?!) will raise a `OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer` error.

Comment: On Windows, `a` and `b` top row is `-2147483648` (largest negative 32-bit signed value, `long` is 32-bit on Windows) instead, and all of `c` is `inf`.  Seems like `numpy` is skipping a type check somewhere.

Comment: There exist some open issues regarding this behaviour https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6109 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14412. The first issue's comment denotes that these are implications of C compiler rules.

Comment: @MarkTolonen this shouldn't be OS-specific; you can definitely have 64-bit builds of Numpy (and Python) on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The integer literal arguments to `repeat` and `arange` cause the returned arrays to have an integer type. The `empty` does not have a similar literal argument and has a `dtype` argument instead, which defaults to a `float` type.

See the `0.0` and `9.0` below:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

a = np.repeat(0.0, 9).reshape((3, 3))
a[0, :] = np.ones((3,)) * math.inf
print(a)

b = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
b[0, :] = np.ones((3,)) * math.inf
print(b)
```

```
[[inf inf inf]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
[[inf inf inf]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

As to why `-9223372036854775808`:

The `float` to `integer` conversion uses the [cvttsd2si](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttsd2si) instruction which returns 1 followed by 63 zeros to signify error:

> If a converted result exceeds the range limits of signed quadword integer (in 64-bit mode and REX.W/VEX.W/EVEX.W = 1), the floating-point invalid exception is raised, and if this exception is masked, the indefinite integer value (80000000_00000000H) is returned.

which if interpreted as a 2's complement integer, corresponds to `-2^63 = -9223372036854775808`.